# Telethon добавить обработчик на публичный канал

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

У меня есть код:

```
client.add_event_handler(callback, telethon.events.NewMessage(chats=[source_id]))
```

Проблема в том что он работает для открытых групп только тогда, когда на них кликнули в поиске телеграмм или вступили в нее. Я хочу делать это без вступления в группу.

Я пробовал: получать сообщения, получать информацию о группе, прокидывать ивент просмотра сообщений, но ничего не помогло.

Так же я заметил что если ты хоть раз вступил в такую группу, то обработчик можно будет добавить даже если покинул ее. Сообщения из группы можно получать без проблем, но обработчик так просто не добавить.